# Can't unwarp images inside a flex container somehow?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, responsive

I am having a flex-container with multiple other flex containers. Inside each of them, an image and a `<p>` exists. The img (a checkmark) warps on lower screens, I tried `height: auto;` and `max-width: 100%;` but as soon as the screen gets too short, the checkmark warps, seen here:

[image]

```css
.leistungen .headline {
        background: #129DE0;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 40px;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;   
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .leistungen .headline h2 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .leistungen .services {
        background: #129DE0;
        
    }
    
    .leistungen .services .servicesHolder {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        max-width: 1300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .leistungen .services .service {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 20px;
        max-width: 500px;
    }
    
    .leistungen .services .service img {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 3rem;
        height: auto;
        margin-right: 2rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class="leistungen">
            <div class="headline">
                <h2>Das bieten wir:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="services">
            <div class="servicesHolder">
                
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I guess it has to do with the flex-container, but I don't know..

Comment: Didn't understood what you need here? could you elaborate the issue.

Comment: @Manjuboyz I need a way to always display the images correct, not like on the screen. The height should fit with the width, and it doesn't even if I give it a "height: auto;".

Comment: Do you mean wrap or resize instead of warp?

Comment: @RamondeVries Oh.. yes, I mean resize

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` and `vw` for auto adjust of images:

[fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/6wy1dja5/15/) to playaround.

```css
.leistungen .headline {
  background: #129DE0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.leistungen .headline h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.leistungen .services {
  background: #129DE0;
}

.leistungen .services .servicesHolder {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.leistungen .services .service {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.leistungen .services .service img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="leistungen">
        <div class="headline">
            <h2>Das bieten wir:</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="services">
        <div class="servicesHolder">
            
        <div class="service">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="service">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="service">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="service">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="service">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="service">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The image still gets uncorrect on lower screens, can't I use the height attribut on flex-images?

Comment: you can but if you want the images to set based on the screen resolution `vh` and `vw` are the best option, above is just a example you can choose whichever size you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed some css and i think this is the expected result, the image keeps being visible and resizes as a square. this can be done with `object-fit: contain;` on the `img`

```css
.leistungen .headline {
        background: #129DE0;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 40px;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;   
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .leistungen .headline h2 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .leistungen .services {
        background: #129DE0;
        
    }
    
    .leistungen .services .servicesHolder {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        max-width: 1300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .leistungen .services .service {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 20px;
        max-width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    /* added styling for img */
    .leistungen .services .service img {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 3rem;
        height: auto;
        margin-right: 2rem;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid black;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
    /* added styling for p */
    .leistungen .services .service p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        max-width: 90%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="leistungen">
            <div class="headline">
                <h2>Das bieten wir:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="services">
            <div class="servicesHolder">
                
            <div class="service">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `height: 100%;` and `width: auto;` for the image. That way it will become as high as the text and the width will be adjusted according to the proportion of the image (in your case equal to the height since they are squares). In addition you could set a `max-height` to not exceed a certain size. That could be defined as a pixel value, but also using the `vw` unit to make it relative to the screen width (optionally with one or more media queries):

```css
.leistungen .headline {
        background: #129DE0;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 40px;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;   
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .leistungen .headline h2 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .leistungen .services {
        background: #129DE0;
        
    }
    
    .leistungen .services .servicesHolder {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        max-width: 1300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .leistungen .services .service {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 20px;
        max-width: 500px;
    }
    
    .leistungen .services .service img {
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 15vw;
        width: auto;
        margin-right: 2rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class="leistungen">
            <div class="headline">
                <h2>Das bieten wir:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="services">
            <div class="servicesHolder">
                
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="service">
                <img src="bilder/icons/check.png">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can play around with `min-width` instead of `max-width`